# Mass remove blank spaces from file names and folder names

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I remove blank spaces from files and folders names, but just at the beginning and at the end of the files and folders names?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are apps that do this but I am not endorsing anything. In my experience, these apps save me hours, if not days, of work as often I need to rename or clean up thousands of images being imported from a camera.

Try searching for something like: Finder, Better, Rename.

Other than that -- you may have to write an AppleScript. There may be an AppleScript already out there. Search for AppleScripts, too.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some thing like this to remove space from start of files:

```
for name in ; do mv -v -- "$name" "${name# }"; done
```

maybe some thing like this to remove space from end of files:

```
for name in *; do mv -v -- "$name" "${name#% }"; done
```

uses for loop with parameter expansion http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

Comment: You should always use the `-i` or `-n` option to `mv` when doing any automated move/rename operation like this -- without one of those options, `mv` will silently delete any files with conflicting names (and if there are bugs in the script, that could be a *lot* of files).

Comment: Fair Point. Depends what you are trying to do. Adjust your flags accordingly. https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv . Manually checking every file can be arduous.